# Custom members in c++ exception type

Tags: c++

Can I derive from `std::runtime_exception` and add my own members? Or is it a problem to add members because of slicing? Do C++ exceptions get copied/assigned in normal use? Does having a virtual destructor ensure that at least I won't leak memory (assuming I plan on recovering from the exception)?

Comment: C++ Exceptions behave the exact same as any other object.
if you catch an object, `catch (const MyException e)`, object slicing will occur.
You can catch by reference `catch (const MyException& e)` to make the exception behave polymorphically

Comment: Slicing isn't an issue, and neither are virtual destructors. But there's a recommendation that exceptions shouldn't throw when copied.

Comment: It's generally inadvisable for an exception to have members that can throw when created or copied.  There are a few reasons for that - not least of which that it may result in the exception that is propagated being different from the exception that is expected.